# Insert text in a table cell with d3

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I add text to a cell using d3?

I have a function with the code that needs to be added and I'm calling this in the body of the html page. I have the following code as an example but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href ="styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function t1(){
    d3.select("td#target").text("14");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="t1()">
  <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td is="target"> </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a small mistake..

change `<td is="target">`into `<td id="target">`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I figured out I had just a typo

```
<td is="target"> </td>
```

Should be

```
<td id="target"> </td>
```